# Re-open "What episodes of Doctor Who should I watch first?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions, closed-questions

[What episodes of Doctor Who should I watch first?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2585/143) is

> **closed** as primarily opinion-based

But I think that's a mistake: the  [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) is well established here and I can't see anything else that should cause it to be closed.

Can we please re-open it?

Comment: This isn't a suggested order. It's a subjective "*which episodes are best for x*" question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about closing it instead as a duplicate of [Suggested order to watch entire Dr. Who?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76252/suggested-order-to-watch-entire-dr-who?noredirect=1&lq=1), which (although posted later) is more objectively worded and already has an excellent answer?

This would leave the question closed, but would have the effect of **giving anyone with the same question a signpost to a place where their question may be answered**. That way, we help people as much as possible while still leaving questions closed which should be closed.

Comment: As a note, if this proposal gets enough support (it hasn't yet), I can do it all myself in a couple of clicks - it doesn't require taking the question on two lengthy trips through the review queues.

Comment: I'm not sure of the value of reopening it just to close it again.

Comment: @Valorum As I said, it gives people a signpost to a still-open question which has the answer they're looking for.

Comment: Having thought about it a bit more, I'm actually reluctant to close this question as a duplicate. It's asking about advice on what to watch **first**, whereas the other question is asking about the order to watch **all** of DW. So they're not really the same question.

Comment: @Randal'Thor You're correct; however, the other answer provides an order which inherently includes a *first*.